# Html to PDF Conversion with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, model-view-controller

I am using Select.HtmltoPdf.
Below ismy code:

```
            var directory = @"D:\Folder\";
        html = html.Replace("/Content", HttpContext.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath + "/Content");
        var filePath = directory + Guid.NewGuid() + ".pdf";
        var converter = new HtmlToPdf(1536,1536);

        converter.Options.EmbedFonts = false;
        converter.Options.ExternalLinksEnabled = true;
        converter.Options.InternalLinksEnabled = true;
        converter.Options.KeepTextsTogether = false;
        converter.Options.KeepImagesTogether = false;
        converter.Options.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

        var pdf = converter.ConvertHtmlString(html, Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority +
Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + "/");

        pdf.Save(filePath);
```

My css is on Content/Site.css
to get the html, i just use $("#printpage").html(); and then pass that to the controller via ajax call which is on Scripts/xx/custom/common.js. problem is it doesnt look the same way as it does on the browser. no css are beign loaded. how do I use select.htmltopdf to render css too? Or if there are any other usable packages out there that can do the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem by:

Since i only get the .html of a certain div in my page, the html, head, body parts of the html arent included.

What i did was to concatenate them and use the css via

```
<link rel="stylesheet">.....
```

`<link rel="stylesheet">`.....and add the necessary tags

Answer (score 0):

What I use to print all the page with css is:

In head:

```
<script language="Javascript">
   function print(){window.print();}
</script>
```

To print:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()" class="btn_result" >
   Print
</a>
```

And if I don't want something to be printed I do like this:

```
@media print {
.print_invisible{display:none;}
}
```

`display:none` or `visibily:hidden`, it depends of the situation.